# My data is not fetching post route in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, xmlhttprequest, fetch-api

I'm a bit confused with my little project.
I've made a route in node:

```
router.post('/signup', userController.signUp);
```

here's the controller for signup:

```
const signUp = async (req, res, next) => {

const {name, email, password} = req.body;

// check if user already exists
let existingUser;
try{
    existingUser = await User.findOne({email});
} catch (e){
    const error = new HttpError('Signup up failed, please try again later', 500);
    return next(error);
}

if (existingUser){
    const error = new HttpError('User already exists, please login instead', 422);
    return next(error);
}

// hash password
let hashedPassword;
try{
    hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 12);
} catch (e){
    const error = new HttpError('Could not crate user, please try again', 500);
    return next(error);
}

// create new user
const createdUser = new User({
    name,
    email,
    password: hashedPassword
})

// save new user
try {
    await createdUser.save();
} catch (e){
    const error = new HttpError('Signing up failed, please try again.', 500);
    return next(error);
}

// generate token
let token;
try {
    token = jwt.sign({
        userID: createdUser.id,
        email: createdUser.email
    }, 'supersecret_dont_share', {expiresIn: '1h'});
} catch (e) {
    const error = new HttpError('Signing up failed, please try again.', 500);
    return next(error);
}

// send response
res.status(201).json({user: createdUser.id, email: createdUser.email, token });

}
```

I'm trying to create a user from the front end:

```
const getUsers = async (e) => {

   e.preventDefault();

        const data = {
            "name": "testttt",
            "password": "testtt2",
            "email": "test@das.com"
        }
        const response = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/users/signup', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify(data)
        });
    console.log(response)

    return response.json(); 
    }
```

And I got this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTMHM.png

also I use in `app.js` (server):

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// cors headers
app.use( (req, res, next) => {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content Type, Accept, Authorization');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PATCH, DELETE');
    next();
} );

// routes
app.use('/users', userRoutes);
```

The problem is that I cannot create a new user, when I console log `req.body` in controller, it shows me an empty object, but when I'm trying to create a user from postman it works.

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Please see [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) and [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: Well, you're getting a 500 error.  I'd suggest you insert enough `console.log()` statements in your server code so you can see exactly where the 500 error is coming from.

Comment: it can enter in any, because the req.body is empty

Comment: the probleam was with body.parse, now i use app.use(express.json()) and works fine.